# Which kind of gradient should I use on a gauge

Tags: gradient

So I have this gauge in an iOS app that has a linear gradient from left to right on on arc inside of it like this

[image: correct gague]

That works well when I only need the gradient to stop in the middle, but when I want to shift the gradient back a little bit, as you can see, it bleeds the upper green part into to the lower part of the dial since it's only linear and those sections overlap.

[image: gague incorrect]

My question is this:

**Which kind of gradient should I use that would rotate colors around a circle?**

I know it's not radial, because that would have the same color on the axis in which I am drawing it on.

Comment: what software are you using? This is a snap in Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: @RandyJones Oddly enough this is actually being drawn in code, but nonetheless, this snap thing, does it snap the gradient to a path? Or what exactly does it do?

Comment: I meant to say that it's very easy to do, as in 'done in a snap' :) And yes, it's possible in Illustrator to give a path a gradient. Are you using css to draw this? It might be an idea to include in your question what you're using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term you a re looking for is an *angle gradient*. This plots the gradient along a circular path and fills the area with it. Lots of image desgin software (like Photoshop) will allow you to make one.

[image: angle gradient example]

In your case, I'd create one that has the 'split' on the bottom, as in the image.

An alternative in vector software (like Adobe Illustrator) would be to have a *gradient stroke*, applying a gradient to a path:

[image]